# Get child node by name in Umbraco 7.8.1

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

My Content structure is:

> ```
> -Home (the site root node)
>   -About Us
>   -Our Sevice1
>   -Our Sevice2
>   -Our Sevice3
> ```

I created a macro for Our Services.
In macro, I want Our Sevice1, Our Sevice2, Our Sevice3...
But in the list variable About Us also come but I don't want it
I want only our service name of the child node

```
  var list= CurrentPage.Children();
```

About Us also come on the list but I don't want it.

Comment: Please Explain more

Comment: @IbraHim I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you see the `About Us` page in the collection is because you use the `Children` method.

With the `Children` method you ask for the direct child nodes of a parent node traversing one level down. So in this case you ask for all direct children of the home page so this works like expected.

What you are trying to achieve is a collection of of all `Service` nodes. To accomplish this you could do something like this.

Make sure that you have a seperated Document Type for your service nodes ( like for example doc type `Service Page` ).

Then you can do the following:

```
var servicePages = CurrentPage.ServicePages;
```

You can view the docs about it here:

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/dynamicpublishedcontent/collections

But all of this is using dynamic syntax, this will be removed in future versions of Umbraco. So I suggest you go and use the strongly type syntax.

Then this can be changed by:

```
var servicePages = Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.DocmentTypeAlias == "servicePage");
```

What this does is take the `IPublishedContent` object of the current page you are on, which is the **Home Page** then you take all children which has a document type alias of type `servicePage`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but in for loop foreach (var item in servicePages) I get item.ServiceName its give me an error

Comment: Yes correct because that's only possible when using dynamics. Now you can use `item.GetPropertyValue("propertyAliasName")`

Comment: Yes its work for me for textbox and other but when I use media picker  then image path don't get

Comment: That will be another question but you can find the solution of here: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/73833-getting-content-from-media-picker-strongly-typed#comment-236652

Answer (score 0):

Like @Mivaweb mentioned, it's better to not use dynamics (I think for performance in addition to being removed in the future).

However, I don't think you have to create a separate doc type, although that will work too.  The predicate for the Where method should handle other expressions such as:

```
var servicePages = Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Our Sevice"));
```

Comment: This solution would do the trick for now, but since Umbraco is a cms and end users can change the name of a content node, this could break functionality. I way I've tackled this problem is by adding a readonly property to the document type that functions like an alias and query by that field.